# What does struct.calcsize (python) actually calculate?

Tags: python

Following [the manual about struct.calcsize](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html)

```
truct.calcsize(fmt)¶

    Return the size of the struct (and hence of the string) corresponding to the given format
```

But I do not get why struct.calcsize('hll') is not struct.calcsize('h') plus two times of struct.calcsize('l'). See below. Any idea?

```
In [216]: struct.calcsize('hll')
Out[216]: 24

In [217]: struct.calcsize('h')
Out[217]: 2

In [218]: struct.calcsize('l')
Out[218]: 8
```

Comment: "*By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved.*" I don't understand how this works exactly, but this is probably part of the explanation. Maybe the `l` always also needs 8 bytes for alignment when packed with other fields, but when it's alone that can be omitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume this is due to padding elements shorter than a machine word, for efficiency purposes.

Accesses to memory addresses that are multiples of the machine word length (e.g. 8 bytes for 64-bit machines) tend to be faster. For this reason, C compilers will pad their structs, unless told otherwise. The `struct` module will do the same for interoperability.

It looks like it's configurable though, depending on how you plan to use it.

Answer (score 0):

But it is still weird that if we change the order of the elements, we get different results, e,g:

```py
In [187]: struct.calcsize('lhh')
Out[187]: 12

In [188]: struct.calcsize('hlh')
Out[188]: 18

In [189]: struct.calcsize('hhl')
Out[189]: 16
```

Considereing what @Vlad said, shouldnt it be all the same size?

But yeah, it seems that is related to some alignment for performance and checking this example:

```py
In [195]: struct.calcsize('hlh')
Out[195]: 18

In [196]: struct.calcsize('llh')
Out[196]: 18

In [197]: struct.pack('hlh', 1, 2, 3)
Out[197]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00'

In [198]: struct.pack('llh', 1, 2, 3)
Out[198]: b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00'
```

One can see that by adding the long next to the short (h), basically converted the short to a long.

But this is quite confusing, because theoretically, we should be able to do the following:

```py
In [199]: struct.unpack('hlh', b'\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00')
```

But actually we cant and python throws an error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-199-41f8bd79fd25> in <module>
----> 1 struct.unpack('hlh', b'\x01\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00')

error: unpack requires a buffer of 18 bytes
```